# How does .Attach differ from .Add in Entity framework 6.1?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I am using the repository from here

[genericunitofworkandrepositories](https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/documentation)

The following two methods are used in the repository:

```
    public virtual void Insert(TEntity entity)
    {
        ((IObjectState) entity).ObjectState = ObjectState.Added;
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _context.SyncObjectState(entity);
    }

    public virtual void InsertGraph(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

Can someone explain what the difference is between the Attach and SyncObjectState and the .Add

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is code partially specific to open source project you are using - not to EF directly so why don't you check the source code? Isn't it a benefit of using open source?

In short:

- `InsertGraph` will take your entity and all its relations and add them to context - all entities in the graph will be inserted to database as new ones.
- `Insert` will only insert the entity you are passing and all relations will hopefully not be inserted (if you didn't manipulate their state elsewhere). The `SyncObjectState` just translates framework specific state representation to EF state representation.